# Access name of custom style used for Android TextView

Tags: android, fonts, styles, typeface

We are using custom styles for our Android app and at the same time experiment with custom typefaces. As I cannot set a custom typeface via xml we defined a subclass of textview and set the font there. However, it would be nice to be able to adjust the font (not its style, i.e., regular, bold, italic,...) via the xml as well.

The basic idea would be to look at what style we have and exploit its name for figuring out wich font to use.

The styles could look like this:

```
<style name="MyFont">
  <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
<style name="MyFont.Font1"></style>
<style name="MyFont.Font2"></style>
```

And the TextView itself could be

```
<com.project.some.OurTextView 
  style="@style/MyFont.Font1" 
  android:text="@string/hello" />
```

If in `com.project.some.OurTextView` I could find out that the styles' name is actually either `Font1` or `Font2`, I would be able to switch cases and use fonts based on this.

So, the question remains: is it possible to access the styles name?

As always, help is highly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="MyFont" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
<style name="MyFont.Font1"></style>
<style name="MyFont.Font2"></style>
```

try the above style.xml file every style element must has parent tag.
Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Hmm, actually this is not what I was asking. Also, you are wrong. The parent is defined by inheriting from my custom style via the dot. I only forgot giving a parent to the "root" element. Following your own link you can read: "Note: This technique for inheritance by chaining together names only works for styles defined by your own resources. You can't inherit Android built-in styles this way. To reference a built-in style, such as TextAppearance, you must use the parent attribute."

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... like that it's correct. Still, would you have an idea how in the actual class file I could find out that the style's name is "Font1"?